# Show different notice message for the update action based on another action in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm doing a user onboard showing a form with data submitted and fetched from Twitter and I'm using the same form for `update` action but in a different route, if the user submitted the form he will be directed to his profile page (doing a basic update to his profile). I just want a different notice message for this step because it's using the `update` action one, so the user can know the profile is created no updated.

`users/finish_signup.html.haml`

```
= simple_form_for(@user) do |f|
  = f.input_field :name
  = f.submit t('go')
```

Routes

```
get ':id', :to => "users#show"
get ':id/finish', :to => "users#finish_signup", :as => 'finish_signup'
```

Finish finish signup method

```
def finish_signup
    # ...
    # for example
    # redirect_to user_show_path_helper(@user), :notice => t('sucess_profile_created')
end
```

Update method

```
def update
    @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @page_has_darker_background = true

    if @user.update(user_params)
      redirect_to user_show_path_helper(@user), :notice => t('sucess_profile_update')
    else
      render 'edit'
    end

end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after doing `@user.update(user_params)` , you check what is your user_params and accordingly set notice messages. 
Eg. if `params[:user][:first_name]` then `notice:` first name updated OR
       `params[:user][:last_name]` then `notice:` last name updated and then `redirect_to user_show_path_helper(@user)`

Comment: I'm using the same form in this step and also in the profile setting page and in the two steps the data already stored. The purpose of this step is to let the user check their info and then be informed that their profile is created not updated. (behind the scenes they actually doing a profile update)

Comment: but there must be at-least one field non-common ... use that field to validate

Comment: Yes I added a hidden field and validated based on it. Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1):

As @gaurav advised, I added a hidden field and did a validation based on it.

Form

```
= simple_form_for(@user) do |f|
  = f.input_field :finish_signup, as: :hidden, value: 'finish_signup'
  = f.input_field :name
  = f.submit t('go')
```

Update

```
def update
    @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @page_has_darker_background = true

    if @user.update(user_params)
      redirect_to user_show_path_helper(@user), :notice => params['user']['finish_signup'] ? t('created') : t('update')
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```